# Supplying an Undefined Command as an Argument

Tags: environments, foreach, loops

I am trying to make an environment where you supply a variable name via an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Foreach loops inside align
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{fora}{+m +b}
  {\pgfplotsforeachungrouped #1 in {0,...,5}{#2}}
{}

\begin{document}

  \begin{fora}[\i]
    \i\textit{testing}
  \end{fora}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error on the `\end{fora}` line:

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

The output produced is this:
=0.0[pt¿5.5pt

My intended output is this:
*1testing2testing3testing4testing5testing*

Is there any way I can let the user supply the \i?

Comment: You'd said your first argument is mandatory, but then given it in square brackets - so `[` is picked up and things go wrong. Did you mean to make it optional?

Comment: I meant to make it mandatory, so I added {} instead. That fixed it. Thank you! I'm silly, ha ha.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the first argument with `m`, so it's mandatory. In this case `+m` isn't good, because you don't want to allow `\par`, would you?

But there's a much better way to do it without having to find a good name for the variable, which `\i` isn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{fora}{O{1}mO{1} +b}
  {
   \cs_set:Nn \__melodicat_fora:n { #4 }
   \int_step_function:nnnN { #1 } { #3 } { #2 } \__melodicat_fora:n
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{fora}[0]{5}
#1\textit{testing}
\end{fora}

\begin{fora}{5}
#1\textit{testing}
\end{fora}

\begin{fora}[0]{6}[2]
#1\textit{testing}
\end{fora}

\end{document}
```

The “variable” is denoted by `#1`. The first optional argument is the initial point (default 1), then the mandatory argument is the end point optionally followed by the step.

[image]